# dialogFragment in landscape is not appearing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with a fragment dialog, if the phone is on portrait mode, everything is ok, but when I rotate my phone, in the landscape, if i launch the dialogFragment, only the header of the dialog is visible

i tried this below but it doesn't work

```
override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            if (dialog != null) {
                val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                dialog!!.window!!.setLayout(width, height)
            }
        }
```

[image]

All of my code

[MainActivity](https://github.com/ismailimoh/dialogFragment/blob/master/MainActivity.kt)
[dialogFragment](https://github.com/ismailimoh/dialogFragment/blob/master/ItemListDialogFragment.kt)
[Layouts](https://github.com/ismailimoh/dialogFragment/tree/master/layout)

Comment: Can you post full code please'

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS please check again the question

Comment: Can you upgrade your full project please? :D

Comment: nothing is missing my project also i am using the dialogfragment sample of the android studio

Comment: I mean I'd like you to upload the full project so I can clone, otherwise if I only have this I need to find your dependencies etc...

Comment: hey please check https://github.com/ismailimoh/bottom-sheet

Comment: checking it....

Comment: hey Skizo-ozᴉʞS i'm waiting you